# KnockoutJS bindings are applied before my ViewModel is actually created

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I think the way i put the question was misleading you, so i've made a major edit.
I will use code from knockoutjs tutorial

> "Loading and saving data", step 3

I've made one change to show what i mean.

```
function Task(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
}

function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() });
    });

    // Operations
    self.addTask = function() {
        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
        self.newTaskText("");
    };
    self.removeTask = function(task) { self.tasks.remove(task) };

    // ** Read this!!
    // This below is the original code in the tutorial, used to fetch remote data.
    // I commented this out, and i will use the below load() method instead.
    // **
    //$.getJSON("/tasks", function(allData) {
    //    var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Task(item) });
    //    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
    //});

    // This is the load method to emulate the above commented
    // $.get. Please, DO NOT CARE about the implementation, or
    // the setTimeout usage, etc., this method ONLY EXISTS TO
    // EMULATE A SLOW SERVER RESPONSE.
    // So, we have to ways of using it:
    //     - load('slow'), will set result after 1 second
    //     - any other argument will set result instantly.
    self.load = function(howFast) {
        if (howFast == 'slow') {
            setTimeout(function(){
                mappedTasks = [];
                mappedTasks.push(new Task({
                    title: 'Some task slowly loaded from server', 
                    isDone: false
                }));
            }, 1000);
        } else {
             mappedTasks = [];
             mappedTasks.push(new Task({
                 title: 'Some task quick!', 
                 isDone: false
             }));
        }
    }

    // Now please note this:
    // - if i use load(), mappedTask is instant updated and
    //   everything runs fine
    // - if i use load('slow'), mappedTask is updated AFTER
    //   VALUES ARE BOUND, so if you open your browser console
    //   you will see an "Uncaught ReferenceError: mappedTasks is not defined" error.
    self.load();
    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
}


ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

**PROBLEM**: Bindings are applied **AFTER** the ViewModel has done with initializazions, therefore causing errors. I think i provided enough detail in code comments, ask me if you think you need more. Anyway, i am little amazed that nobody ever hit this thing before, so am i missing something VERY important here?

**QUESTION**: How to avoid this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6MUq/2/)

Comment: I haven't used knockout in a while, I might be misunderstanding: http://jsfiddle.net/cjuZZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have an html error.

Your setTimeout function is attempting to programmatically set the selected option to an option that isn't in the list. The browser can't do that and so the selection stays where it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/UD89R/6/

```
function ViewModel() {
    // Setup something.
    var self = this;
    self.foo = ko.observable();
    self.options = ko.observableArray([{id:1, name:'Homer'}, {id:2, name:'Barney'}]);

    // Make a lot of async data load, like    
    // $.get('this', function(){  /* Process data */ });
    // $.get('that', anotherHandler);
    // $.get('somethingElse', self.someObservable);

    // Assume the whole process would take 1 second.
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.options.push({id: 3, name: 'Grimes'});
        self.foo(3);
        // Too late! foo has been overriden by the select-options binding,
        // so this one will not log 'Grimes' as expected.
        console.log('Loading done, check foo value:' + self.foo());
    }, 1000);    
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't with the select option, it's about a late binding issue